# fopen reading from a variable

Tags: c, operating-system, fopen

I have been working on this operating system project using a FAT-12 file system.  Recently I went to make it so that each command was running of the same disk.  To do this i just added a string to shared memory.  However, upon pulling the information from the shared memory and passing it into fopen i get the error message "Could not open the floppy drive or image." To fix this problem i have already ensured that I have read write permissions and that the floppy images were not corrupted from working on commands such as mkdir and rmdir.  I have even tried undoing the changes that made the processes share a floppy image and the problem did not resolve.  If you have any ideas why this could be happening, feedback would be appreciated.

This where I'm reading the floppy image with fopen and where I the debug statement is:

```
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
       // unimportant code

       // get shared memory
       FileInfo_retrieve();
       fprintf(stderr, "Current Disk(ls): %s\n", FileInfo_getPointer()->currentDisk);
       //FILE_SYSTEM_ID declared as a global variable
       FILE_SYSTEM_ID = fopen(FileInfo_getPointer()->currentDisk, "r+");
       FileInfo_detach();

       if(FILE_SYSTEM_ID == NULL)
       {
         printf("Could not open the floppy drive or image.\n");
         exit(1);
       }

       // more unimportant code
    }
```

This is the definition of the struct stored in shared memory:

```
    // from the shared memory header
    #define MAX_FILE_PATH_SIZE 2048

    typedef struct FileInfo_STRUCT
    {
      char filename[9];
      char extension[4];
      char cwd[MAX_FILE_PATH_SIZE];
      char currentDisk[32];
      int FLC;
      int TotalEntries;
      int TotalAvailableEntries;
    } FileInfo;
```

This is where i declare everything that goes into the shared memory at runtime:

```
    // declared in header
    bool FileInfo_Init(const char* dirName, const char* currDir, int FLC)
    {
      if(FileInfo_create())
      {
        strcpy(FileInfo_getPointer()->fileName, dirName);
        strcpy(FileInfo_getPointer()->cwd, currDir);
        strcpy(FileInfo_getPointer()->currentDisk, "../floppysInUse/floppy1");

        FileInfo_getPointer()->FLC = FLC;

        // searches fat table at runtime and finds how much of the disk is available
        StartUp();

        FileInfo_getPointer()->TotalEntries = total;
        FileInfo_getPointer()->TotalAvailableEntries = available;

        FileInfo_detach();
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    }
```

This is the output after running a command. A debug statement and the error i get from opening the file:

```
         Current Disk(ls): ../floppyInUse/floppy1
         Could not open the floppy drive or image.
```

Comment: If you trace with `gdb`, what is the value of `FileInfo_getPointer()->currentDisk` when you call `fopen()`? What's the value of `errno`?

Comment: I'm confused... you're trying to read the disk contents as a file?  I've done that kind of thing before, but with `dd` linux/unix command to dump the device contents into a file, not my own program.

Comment: It sounds like this struct is shared with multiple processes via shared memory. Is there anything to manage access to the shared memory to prevent race conditions?

Comment: @DaveNewman since only one command can be run at a time there are no race conditions. By the time another command tries to access the shared memory the first has already detached from it.

Comment: @FatalError I used fprintf to print out the contents of FileInfo_getPointer()->currentDisk right before i call it in fopen, and it is the last block of code i posted where it says Current Dist(ls): ../floppyInUse/floppy1

Comment: @JayC The disks are already in file format and I'm just trying to read the disk using fopen

Comment: Which value is set `errno` to?

Comment: Thank you for all of your help I was able to find a solution by all of your digging.

Comment: Your `fopen()` that is failing uses "r+" (reading and writing).  Since you say you are " just trying to read the disk using fopen", recommend using "r" (reading) as that may require fewer unique resources from a shared resource.

Comment: You might like to answer your own question though.

Answer (score 0):

OP says he's found a solution, although he doesn't say what it was. [(here's the comment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854240/fopen-reading-from-a-variable#comment22623191_15854240)